# How to set background of recyclerview while items are loading?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my app that I want to set the `background` to black. 
I already tried setting the background of the recyclerview using the `background` attribute but it only sets the black background on the parts of the recyclerview which has items.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_card">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

If the recycler view does not fill the whole screen the bottom part is always white. And when the activity is just opened and the items for the recyclerview is still loading the recyclerview only shows as blank (white) space.

How do you basically set the background of a recyclerview?

EDIT: Here is the whole layout

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_card">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole XML file where you have the RV?

Comment: @Notsileous I already added the whole layout

Comment: Just make the Height of `NestedScrollView` **match_parent** and set the background color to  `NestedScrollView`. It works

Answer (score 2):

Putting a recyclerview inside of a scrollview is never a good idea, and also not needed. The reason you are having issues is because your trying to match parent on something without a defined height because its in a scrollview.
really the only two things you need is the RV and the progress bar, use a relative layout and align the RV to the top, the PB to the bottom and set the RV to layout above the PB. Set the color of the relative layout to black and you dont need to color the RV at all.

Comment: This would make the progressbar always visible on the screen, instead of only visible when the content is scrolled all the way to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of how you've defined your layout. Nesting a `match_parent` RecyclerView inside of a `wrap_content` LinearLayout will behave approximately the same as just defining a `wrap_content` RecyclerView.

Given your layout, I think you're trying to implement an "infinite" RecyclerView that loads more content when you scroll to the bottom. If this is the case, you probably want to re-think your layout and app somewhat; a better approach would be to use a RecyclerView *without* a NestedScrollView, and use item types to make sure that the last item in your RecyclerView is the loading indicator.

If you don't want to do that, I recommend setting the `android:background` attribute on the NestedScrollView instead of the RecyclerView. You could then set the background of the loading indicator to some other color if you don't want it to have the same black background. Note, though, that your app's performance is likely to degrade if you follow this "easy" path, since you'll be losing the recycling behavior of RecyclerView.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Will definitely go with the better way.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since you edit your question, you should define `minHeight`.

You can achieve by using `background` property.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/items"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/your_color"
     android:minHeight="200dp"
     tools:listitem="@layout/item_card">
 </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```